# How to export all my GitHub account content in one action, delete the account and then import the exported content into a new GitHub account?

Tags: git, github

I think about creating a new GitHub account, free from any previous communal collaboration and yet before I delete my account I want to export all of my repositories in one action instead download their zip files one by one.

How to export all my GitHub account content in one action, delete the account and then import the exported content into a new GitHub account?
I'd assume that some Git algorithm exists and implementable.

Comment: *Do not* use GitHub's "download a zip file" option. That does not copy the *repository* at all. Instead, that turns one commit into a zip file, which you then obtain as a zip file: one snapshot from one commit only.

Answer (score 3):

> I'd assume that some Git algorithm exists and implementable.

Git knows nothing about GitHub and has no way to discover remote repositories.

Your best option is probably going to be the [github cli](https://cli.github.com/). You can get a list of all your repositories using the `gh repo list` command. Something like this would let you clone all of your repositories into the current directory:

```
gh repo list -L1000 --json sshUrl | jq -r '.[]|.sshUrl' | while read url; do
    git clone --mirror $url
done
```

(The `-L1000` there is because `gh repo list` will only display information about 30 repositories by default. If you have more than 1000 repositories, increase the number as appropriate.)

You could upload all your repositories to a new account by iterating over the cloned repositories and using the `gh` command to create a new repository on GitHub, and then `git push` the content:

```
for repo in *; do
  git -C $repo remote set-url origin git@github.com:mynewuser/$repo
  git -C $repo push --all origin
done
```

This is all untested, but hopefully gives you an idea of where to start.

Comment: I have only about 7 repos

Comment: `$url` contains github.com/user correct? and what does `$repo` contains?

Comment: In the first loop, `$url` contains subsequent lines read from the output of `gh repo list --json sshUrl | jq -r '.[]|.sshUrl'`. In the second loop, we are iterating over file/directory names (and if you started with an empty directory, then these will be the names of the directories created by the `git clone` operation in the first loop).